# ES6 Static method referring to self?

Tags: javascript, static, ecmascript-6

I have two classe; Repository and UserRepository. I want to define a static method in Repository that at runtime calls a static function in UserRepository. Is there any clean way to do this?

```
class Repository {
    static printModel() {
        return console.log(this.constructor.model())
    }
}

class UserRepository extends Repository {
    static model() {
        return "I am a user";
    }
}

UserRepository.printModel(); // Doesn't work; want it to print "I am a user"
```

Now it makes sense that the above doesn't work, as this probably referes to an instance, and I have no instances in this case.

My question is, how do I refer to the subclass method `model()` from the baseclass?

Comment: Just tested it and `this.model();` seems to do the trick. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now it makes sense that the above doesn't work, as this probably referes to an instance, and I have no instances in this case.

No, how would `this` refer to an instance, as you say you don't have any?

No, static methods are just functions like any other methods as well, and `this` refers to whatever they were invoked on. In `UserRepository.printModel();`, `this` will refer to `UserRepository`. And you can just use `this.model()` to call the static `.model()` method of that class.