# Javascript access to static child attributes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have this situation

```
import assert from 'assert'

class A {
    static x = 0

    static a () {
        return A.x
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static x = 1
}

assert.equal(B.a(), 1)
```

i need to retrive static value in derived class from base class in Js es6.
but, i can't find a way,

the assertion will fails with

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 0 == 1
```

what's the right way to do this?

- thanks

Comment: You're asking for `A.x`, what other value could it give you? Try `this.x`.

Comment: It seems to work: https://repl.it/repls/IndolentNeighboringRhesusmonkey

Comment: You can use `this` in a static method, it will refer to the class. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34056740/369

Comment: yes is working. thanks a lot, i did not think about that... :sad:

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're asking for `A.x` directly. You should call `this.x` to get `A.x` when you are on an object of kind `A` and to get `B.x` when you are on an object of kind `B`.

Just make following changes and it should work fine:

```
static a () {
    return this.x;
}
```