# JS Is there a way to get name of child class in a STATIC parent class?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the classname "User" from a static function within the class "Model".

```
class Model {
  static getName(){
// here is where I would generate the the string "User" (classname of child)
  }
}

class User extends Model {
}


User.getName();
```

This question was already asked but not in a static sciope: [Is there a way to get name of child class in parent class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097947/is-there-a-way-to-get-name-of-child-class-in-parent-class)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052148/es6-static-method-referring-to-self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a static context, `this` is the current class, so simply:

```js
class Model {
  static getName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

class User extends Model {}


User.getName();
```

Comment: Thank you now do you know how I could call a static from that string (this.name).staticFunction()?

Comment: And why would you want to do _that_?! If you just have the name of the class as a string, you'd need to look up the actual object/variable by name, which is all sorts of complex and wrong. You already _have_ `this`, why do you need to turn that into a name and back into a `this` from there?

Comment: Yea nevermind my own code confused me. To call a static from a non static i used "this.constructor.func()" and to call a static from a static i used just "this.func()" Would that be a solid solution?

Comment: Yes. `this` inside a static method _is_ the class object, i.e. `this === User`. So `this.func()` is what you want to call other static methods from a static method.

Comment: Appreciate it very much!